# item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports, qodbc

My code gives the following error. How can I correct this?

> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

```
ElseIf Me.chkItem.Checked = True Then
    Dim CheckNumber As String = ""
    Dim CheckRef As String = ""
    dsvoucheritem.Clear()
    DSVoucher_Expense.Clear()
    DSVoucher_Check.Clear()

    Try
        Me.lstCV.Items.Clear()
        strDiscount = Nothing
        rec.Open("select billpaymentcheckline.txnnumber, billpaymentcheckline.txndate" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.payeeentityreffullname" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.amount, billitemline.itemlineitemreffullname" _
        & ", billitemline.memo" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxndiscountamount" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxnrefnumber, billpaymentcheckline.bankaccountreffullname" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxndiscountaccountreffullname" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxntxndate, billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxnamount" _
        & ", billpaymentcheckline.refnumber, account.AccountNumber from (billitemline inner join" _
        & " billpaymentcheckline on billitemline.refnumber=billpaymentcheckline.appliedtotxnrefnumber) left outer join" _
        & " account on billitemline.APAccountreflistid=account.listid where" _
        & " billpaymentcheckline.bankaccountreflistid='" &Me.lblBankID.Text & "' and" _
        & " billpaymentcheckline.refnumber between '" & CInt(Me.txtRefFR.Text)
        & "' and '" & CInt(Me.txtRefTO.Text) & "'", con, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)
```

Comment: This code is wide open for a sql injection security vulnerability.  Using a parameterized query would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying it doesn't recognize one of your column names. Double check all of them. You can also try removing fields until you find the culprit.

Comment: I remove the outer join and then im getting an error like this  "[QODBC] Lexical element not found"

Comment: The element it will be looking for is account. Does anything reference account.something?

Comment: Your joins are probably working fine. Check your column names instead.

Comment: ok, how about trying just select * from that and seeing what comes back. Are you sure the database your connecting to is the exact schema you're expecting?

Comment: i can't use the select * because i need to get the data in two tables .

Comment: when i use the table billexpenseline and billpaymentcheckline the system run . but when i use the billitemline and billpaymentcheckline im getting those error . i just change the billexpenseline to billitemline . i dont really get why im having those errors

Answer (score 0):

`memo` is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx) in Access SQL.

Try `billitemline.[memo]`